# Entity Framework link in one direction but not back

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, relationship, edmx-designer

I have a database that has a Ticket table and an Issue table. I have a foreign key setup on the Ticket table that IssueId is linked with the Issue tables id.

When I generate the model or code first based on the database the Issue object has a ICollection. Which I am assuming is it will get all tickets with that id. However I am not wanting the relationship in the generated model to actually do that. So from a ticket you can access Issue but from Issue you cannot access any tickets. Is there anyway to make the generation do this for the designer? So it won't create a navigation property on the Issue object to a collection of tickets. So I guess it would be a 1 to 0 relationship?

Is the only way to do this is to manually delete the navigation property in the designer or the code inside the generated code?

Comment: You can simply delete the navigation property in the edmx designer. This will survive model updates.

Comment: but then every time I update the database I have to go through and delete the navigation properties which seems like it would be quite a pain. Is there no way to just make it default?

Comment: A model update won't re-add deleted properties. You may have to remove properties/associations from *new* types. To make it the default, you'd have to edit the t4 template.

Comment: @Insight: are you talking about edmx designer or generate code first from database? I think for edmx designer you have your answer.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Either. They both create it the same way. I can go through and manually update the code as well. I am just wondering if there is a way to make it so it does it automatically.